# how to click the buttons rendered by vue js in jsp pages using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, vue.js, automated-tests

I'm trying to get the button rendered by vue js within jsp page. For normal jsp pages I'm able to find the elements using xpath., but I'm unable to find the elements rendered by vue.js

for ex, my jsp page contains

```
<div id="fileUploadDiv" style="display: flex; border: medium none; height: 620px;">
<object id="mlFirstResponse" style="flex:1;display:flex;border: none;" type="text/html" data="/abc/index.html?abcId=0&amp;=editingPolicy=false&amp;objectHeight=480">
.
.
.
<div data-v-010855a7="" style="width: 100%; float: right;">
<button data-v-1f92dc12="" data-v-010855a7="" class="btn outline" id="clickable_id" style="float:right;padding: 5px 20px;font-size: 13px;">Continue to next page</button>
</div>
.
.
</object>

</div>
```

For this I'm able to find the element using

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fileUploadDiv\"]")), (This id is rendered from jsp page)
```

Similarly I tried to get the button with id="clickable_id", like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"clickable_id\"]")),   (This id is rendered from vue js)
```

But I got no such element found exception errors

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case the button is being loaded **after** [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) finishes loading, i.e. [Document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) property equals `complete` and the button is still not there as it's being added via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request.

Consider adding [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) so WebDriver could wait for some more time till the button is there, it can be done using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) classes combination like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement myButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("clickable_id")));
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply., We tried like this., but still facing the same issue.

new.WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("clickable_id")));

Comment: I used FluenWait, implicit wait also, but still getting same exception